# Create navigation property one-to-one with middle table relationship on EF

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I would like to create a relationship between two directly unrelated tables via a foreign key. But I am not succeeding. Would anyone know if this is possible in the entity framework and how it can be resolved?

Model

[image]

C#

```
class Commentary {
     public int Id {get;set; }
     public int UserId {get; set;}
     public User User {get;set;}
     public UserAccount UserAccount {get;set;}
}

class User {
     public int Id {get;set; }
     public int UserAccountId {get; set;}
     public UserAccount UserAccount {get;set;}
}

class UserAccount {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public ICollection<User> Users {get; set;}
}

// Relationship
modelBuilder.Entity<TarefaComentario>()
  .HasOne(c => c.UserAccount)
  .WithMany()
   .HasForeignKey(c => c.User.UserAccountId) // this generates error
  .HasPrincipalKey(ua => ua.Id);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct relationship between Commentary and UserAccount. The relationship you have is Commentary->User->UserAccount.

So, you have to use `modelBuilder` two times, to create the two relationships. From `Commentary` to `User`, then from `User` to `UserAccount`.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Commentary>()
  .HasOne(c => c.User)
  .WithMany(u => u.Commentaries)
  .HasForeignKey(c => c.UserId);

modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
  .HasOne(u => u.UserAccount)
  .WithMany(ua => ua.Users)
  .HasForeignKey(u => u.UserAccountId);
```

You also have to add `public ICollection<Commentary> Commentaries {get; set;}` to your `User` class.

Now, if you have a `Commentary` object, you can access `User` and `UserAccount` like this: `Commentary.User.UserAccount`.

**EDIT:**

If you want to access the UserAccount directly from the Commentary class, I believe you could have `public UserAccount UserAccount => User.UserAccount;` inside the Commentary class. So every time you select a Commentary, it will include the User, and the `User.UserAccount` will be assigned to the `Commentary.UserAccount`.

Comment: I know this basic relationship works. However, my goal would be to make it easier to access the UserAccount through the Commentary.

Today I have to do this `comment.User.UserAccount.Address`  for example, but I wanted something like `comment.UserAccount.Address`.

Comment: Ok, so maybe, inside the Commentary class, you make `public UserAccount UserAccount => User.UserAccount;`. So every time you select a Commentary, you include the User and make the `Commentary.UserAccount` receive the value of `User.UserAccount`. But you would have to create the two relationships anyway

Comment: I made an Edit in the answer, see if it helps

Comment: Did not work. This is because the entity framework tries to find a relationship between Comment and UserAccount. As it does not exist, it generates the exception Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid column name 'UserAccountId'.'

Comment: Ok, try putting a `[NotMapped]` attribute on top of UserAccount inside Commentary. This should make EF understand it is not a mapped property in the database.

Comment: It's what you said, the only way for this to work is to execute the include in the query(query.Include(a=> a.User.UserAccount)). But I would like to use a way that the entity itself can identify, so I was looking for a way to make this relationship by configuration. Because this is just a scenario, I have others similar

Comment: Oh, I see! Well, since there is no direct relationship between Commentary and UserAccount in the database, I don’t know if it is possible to do it in the code. Maybe it is and I don’t know. Sorry I couldn’t help you